# Регулярные выражения. Разрешить русские символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код, который проверяет введенные в форму ввода символы, и в случае чего выдает ошибку
этот код `if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['title']))` разрешает только английские буквы и цифры. 
А мне нужно чтоб он разрешал английские и русские буквы. 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Каков полный список разрешенных символов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробовали

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]+$/",$_POST['title']))
```

думаю поможет